# Error: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: android, expandablelistview, numberformatexception

How to convert a string to double?

MainActivity.java

```
Location savedLocation = new Location("databaseLocation");
                savedLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
```

Logcat:

```
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locademo/com.example.locademo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at com.example.locademo.MainActivity.getExpandableListData(MainActivity.java:203)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at com.example.locademo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
07-06 14:41:21.870: E/AndroidRuntime(24097):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are trying to cast an **empty string** to a number. Which is **not valid**.

Comment: What's the value of `latitude` ?

Comment: You are type casting null or empty string.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman: Yeah... I got that from the stack trace. But I asked this question to OP, so that he might get where he went wrong.

Comment: When I print the value of latitude in Log so its showing the value of latitude so its not an empty string @DerGolem

Comment: So if you have a value in `latitude`, can you show how do you get that value?

Comment: This is **very clear**: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""`

Comment: Just reading the stacktrace is really helpful...

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid double: " "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672456/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double)

Answer (score 3):

Error clearly shows your value is empty

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
```

You need add one condition like this

```
if (!latitude.equals("")){
Location savedLocation = new Location("databaseLocation");
                savedLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
}
```

Note :
**Whenever you make number format conversion make sure you don't get any empty or null values**

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble(String)` is working fine, but throws an `NumberFormatException` if the supplied value cannot be converted to a `double`. Referring to the second line of your stacktrace:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

means in this case `latitude` had the value `""` (empty string) and the conversion failed. You may implement some checks for blank strings (empty string or *null*), fix the value of `latitude` before it reaches the conversion or `catch` the exception and handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Check that youR latitude value will be null or blank.

```
if (!latitude.equals("")){
// apply your logic
}
```