# Android TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-textwatcher

I am trying to implement TextWatcher to my application, but when I enter a number into the edit text which has text watcher on it it gives me error like this:

```
AndroidRuntime:at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
AndroidRuntime:at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
AndroidRuntime:at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
```

And this is the code inside the text watcher:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    myPercent = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
    myPrice =  Double.parseDouble(priceShow.getText().toString());
    finalPrice = myPrice*(myPercent/100);
    priceAfterDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(finalPrice));
}
```

Comment: What number did you exacly enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add

```
android:inputType="number"
android:singleLine="true"
```

to your `myPercent` `EditText`.

Problem is probably that you are entering `,` instead of `.` as decimal separator.

Use

```
try { 
    if (!s.toString().equals("") && !priceShow.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        myPercent = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        myPrice =  Double.parseDouble(priceShow.getText().toString());
        finalPrice = myPrice*(myPercent/100);
        priceAfterDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(finalPrice));
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to prevent application from crashing.

Comment: yes I have just tried it, it gives me this error message: System.out: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: thank you so much, it worked !!! Can you tell me where was the problem I am really curious :/

Comment: `TextWatcher` detected change within `s`, so `onTextChanged` has been called, but `s` was probably still empty in this moment, so by making `Double.parseDouble(s.toString());` you trying to make `double` from empty `String` `""`. All I did is just adding `if` which prevents execution of this method if `String` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think your edit text value is empty. check first if its empty or not, then do the calculation.
use try catch to find exact problem.
try this,
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672522/3995124)

Comment: It was not empty actually Swapnil, I have tried the solution that Damian provided and it worked, but to be honest I don’t know why :)

Comment: Ok. Exact reason is given by Damian in comment. Hope you understand the reason.

Comment: you were kind of right now Damian explained the problem I didnt notice it