# How add various editText in one TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm new in programming and I need your help, I have a error when insert number in editText txt50, app crashes please help me, I don't know what is the error:

code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private EditText cinco, cien, doscientos, quinientos, mil, dosmil, cincomil, diezmil, veintemil, cincuentamil, cienmil;
    private TextView diezmob;

    public static final String nombres = "names";
    TextView txtBienvenido;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        txtBienvenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
        String usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
        txtBienvenido.setText("¡Bienvenido(a) Hermano(a) " + usuario + "!");

        diezmob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);
        cinco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt50);
        cien = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt100);
        doscientos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt200);
        quinientos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt500);
        mil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1000);
        dosmil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2000);
        cincomil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt5000);
        diezmil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt10000);
        veintemil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt20000);
        cincuentamil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt50000);
        cienmil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt100000);

        cinco.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if ((cinco.toString().equals("")) && (!cinco.toString().equals(null)) && (cinco.toString().isEmpty() || (cinco.toString().length() >= 0))) {
                        double valor1 = Double.parseDouble((cinco.getText().toString()));
                        double valor2 = Double.parseDouble((cien.getText().toString()));
                        double valor3 = Double.parseDouble((doscientos.getText().toString()));
                        double valor4 = Double.parseDouble((quinientos.getText().toString()));
                        double valor5 = Double.parseDouble((mil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor6 = Double.parseDouble((dosmil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor7 = Double.parseDouble((cincomil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor8 = Double.parseDouble((diezmil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor9 = Double.parseDouble((veintemil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor10 = Double.parseDouble((cincuentamil.getText().toString()));
                        double valor11 = Double.parseDouble((cienmil.getText().toString()));
                        double suma = (valor1 * 50) + (valor2 * 100) + (valor3 * 200) + (valor4 * 500) + (valor5 * 1000) + (valor6 * 2000) + (valor7 * 5000) + (valor8 * 10000) + (valor9 * 20000) + (valor10 * 50000) + (valor11 * 100000);
                        String resultado = String.valueOf((int) suma);
                        diezmob.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
                    } else {
                        diezmob.setText("0");
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    } }
```

LogCat: Error when insert number in editText txt50, the app crashes:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid double: " "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672456/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this error with this code, any error please say it.

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView diezmob;

    public static final String nombres = "names";
    TextView txtBienvenido;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        txtBienvenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
        String usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
        txtBienvenido.setText("¡Bienvenido(a) Hermano(a) " + usuario + "!");

        diezmob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);

        findViewById(R.id.btncalcular).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btncalcular5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btncalcular10).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btncalcular15).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btncalcular:

                double cinco, cien, doscientos, quinientos, mil, dosmil, cincomil, diezmil, veintemil, cincuentamil, cienmil;

                String Cinco = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt50)).getText().toString();
                String Cien = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt100)).getText().toString();
                String Doscientos = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt200)).getText().toString();
                String Quinientos = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt500)).getText().toString();
                String Mil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1000)).getText().toString();
                String Dosmil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2000)).getText().toString();
                String Cincomil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt5000)).getText().toString();
                String Diezmil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt10000)).getText().toString();
                String Veintemil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt20000)).getText().toString();
                String Cincuentamil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt50000)).getText().toString();
                String Cienmil = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt100000)).getText().toString();

                if (Cinco != null && !Cinco.equals("")) {
                    cinco =  Double.valueOf(Cinco);

                }else{
                    cinco = 0;

                }

                if (Cien != null && !Cien.equals("")){
                    cien =   Double.valueOf(Cien);

                }else{
                    cien=0;

                }

                if (Doscientos != null && !Doscientos.equals("")) {
                    doscientos =  Double.valueOf(Doscientos);

                }else{
                    doscientos=0;

                }

                if (Quinientos != null && !Quinientos.equals("")) {
                    quinientos = Double.valueOf(Quinientos);

                }else{
                    quinientos = 0;

                }
                if (Mil != null && !Mil.equals("")){
                    mil = Double.valueOf(Mil);

                }else{
                    mil = 0;

                }
                if (Dosmil != null && !Dosmil.equals("")) {
                    dosmil = Double.valueOf(Dosmil);

                }else {
                    dosmil = 0;

                }
                if (Cincomil != null && !Cincomil.equals("")) {
                    cincomil = Double.parseDouble(Cincomil);

                }else {
                    cincomil = 0;

                }
                if (Diezmil !=null && !Diezmil.equals("")) {
                    diezmil = Double.valueOf(Diezmil);

                }else {
                    diezmil = 0;

                }

                if (Veintemil != null && !Veintemil.equals("")) {
                    veintemil = Double.valueOf(Veintemil);

                }else {
                    veintemil = 0;

                }

                if (Cincuentamil != null && !Cincuentamil.equals("") ) {
                    cincuentamil = Double.valueOf(Cincuentamil);

                }else {
                    cincuentamil = 0;

                }

                if (Cienmil != null && !Cienmil.equals("")    ) {
                    cienmil = Double.valueOf(Cienmil);

                }else {
                    cienmil = 0;

                }



                double suma = (cinco * 50) + (cien * 100) + (doscientos * 200) + (quinientos * 500) + (mil * 1000) +
                            (dosmil * 2000) + (cincomil * 5000) + (diezmil * 10000) + (veintemil * 20000) + (cincuentamil * 50000) +
                            (cienmil * 100000);
                    String resultado = String.valueOf((int)(suma));
                    diezmob.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));

                break;

            case R.id.btncalcular5:

                Intent i = new Intent(this, Main5Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("dato",diezmob.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);

                break;

            case R.id.btncalcular10:
                Intent ii = new Intent(this, Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(ii);
                break;

            case
                    R.id.btncalcular15:
                Intent iii = new Intent(this, Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(iii);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate this:

```java
if ((cinco.toString().equals("")) && (!cinco.toString().equals(null)) && (cinco.toString().isEmpty() || (cinco.toString().length() >= 0))) {
                        double valor1 = Double.parseDouble((cinco.getText().toString()));
```

You are saying if ("cinco is an empty string") and (not null) and ((isEmpty(same as empty string)) or is a length >= 0) then parse double

I am pretty sure the only time this evaluates to true is if cinco is empty which will result in a NumberFormatException because you are trying to parse cinco for a double while it is empty. You will have to handle exceptions with a try-catch block:

```java
try {
    double valor1 = Double.parseDouble((cinco.getText().toString()));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or construct if statements that don't allow cinco to be evaluated if it is empty:

```java
if(cinco.toString() != null && !(cinco.toString().isEmpty() {
    double valor1 = Double.parseDouble((cinco.getText().toString()));
}
```

edit: All of the Double.parseDouble in your code will throw NumberFormatExceptions not just cinco by the way. That one is just first so this answer applies to all of the parses.

Comment: We both posted similiar answers, I didn't see yours because I was writting mine in the meantime. I'm not sure if I should delete or not but for now I'll keep it and maybe it helps OP.

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak I mean it's up to you but I do appreciate the headsup though.

Comment: @brandonx, thanks for your answer. I would like to know, how I do for to execute the textWatcher when I type in any editText and show me the result in the TextView diezmob?.

Comment: @JairVides it's up to how you want to design this but you would probably write a generic TextWatcher that you register all of your EditTexts to and wrap all of the Parse.doubles in individual try-catches in order to avoid trying to make calculations on empty strings. I think a better option would be to have a button that activates the calculation instead(although you will still need the try-catch or if statements handling empty edittexts).

Comment: Thanks @brandonx, how I do it with a button?