# Why am I getting a fatal error and couldn't execute onClick() on android studio?

Tags: java, android

I just have one activity on my app.I am trying to create a currency converter with 2 edit texts for pounds and dollars to rupees conversion.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void convertCurrency(View view){
        Log.i("Info","Button Pressed");

        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //Dollars to Rupees
        String amountInDollars=editText.getText().toString();
        double amountInDoubleDollars=Double.parseDouble(amountInDollars);
        double amountInRupeesDouble= amountInDoubleDollars*73.67;
        String amountInRupeesString=String.format("%.2f",amountInRupeesDouble);
        Toast.makeText(this, "$"+amountInDollars + " is Rs"+amountInRupeesString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //Pounds to Rupees
        String amountInPounds=editText1.getText().toString();
        double amountInDoublePounds=Double.parseDouble(amountInPounds);
        double amountInRupeesDouble1=amountInDoublePounds*96.4;
        String amountInRupeesString1=String.format("%.2f",amountInRupeesDouble1);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Pounds"+amountInPounds+"is Rs"+amountInRupeesString1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Enter rupees to give the entire list of conversion.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I expect 2 edit text to appear on my app but when i run the above and try and give input for my currency converter but the app abruptly shuts down and gives this error.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.currencyconverter, PID: 27696
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

and also it has following error as well

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: show us your xml as well please

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672456/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double

Comment: Do you mean activity_main.xml?

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: Hello,I just have an activity on my app which has 2 edit texts which are for pounds and dollars to rupees resp.The code is similar for both pounds and dollars except for variable names.When i execute the code and give the input the app shuts abruptly.What more details do you want mate(sir) can you specify?

Answer (score -1):

Probably `Double.parseDouble(s)` fails, because `s` is `""`.

Add:

`Log.d("MainActivity", "amountInDollars: " + amountInDollars);`

and

`Log.d("MainActivity", "amountInPounds: " + amountInPounds);`

one line before you call `Double.parseDouble()`

That way, you'll make sure that you're calling `Double.parseDouble()` with a valid string.